# How can I get the image src?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, getelementbyid, webview2

I'm using a WebView2 on Windows Forms. I want to get that image src from html and show it in a MessageBox

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="z-index:900;padding:0">
<img id="imageCodeDisplayId" width="180" height="50" ng-src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg" alt="Verify Image" style="padding:2px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#CCC;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px" src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg">
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true" title="Reload" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:30px;top:10px;left:10px;text-decoration:none" ng-click="getCaptcha()"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2375#issue-1208145799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById('imageCodeDisplayId').src` to access the src attribute of the img element.

You can use the [`ExecutScriptAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.executescriptasync) method to retrieve the value via C#.

Here you go:

```
// get the src attribute value
string srcAttributeValue = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('imageCodeDisplayId').src");

// show it in a message box
MessageBox.Show(srcAttributeValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript code can be injected into WebView2 controls at runtime using host apps. The injected JavaScript applies to all new top-level documents and any child frames. The JavaScript injected into the page is executed at a precise point in time.

You can use the following java script to select src attribute of specified img tag and then show it in an alert:

```js
alert(document.getElementById('imageCodeDisplayId').attributes['src'].value);
```

So in your WevView2's `EnsureHttps` use something like the following code:

```
void EnsureHttps(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    webView.CoreWebView2
        .ExecuteScriptAsync(@"alert(document.getElementById('imageCodeDisplayId').attributes['src'].value);");
    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Output:

[image: Output of js]

All extra necessary information is available at [Get started with WebView2 in WinForms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms)

And also [WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1185.39) describes everything that you need to use it.